# VSCode won't stop at breakpoints on remote server

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm unable to make VSCode stop at a breakpoint on the app created by `npx create-react-app` on a guest VM running on the same system as VSCode.

I use VSCode on a Windows 10 Pro host connected to a Centos 7 system running on a guest VM using VMWare. I use the "Remote SSH" extension of VSCode and it seems to mostly work. I'm new to this technology stack so please forgive my newbie confusion.

I've set a breakpoint at line six of the `App.js` generated by `create-react-app`. I've done all sorts of permutations of launch.json and package.json, none seem to make any difference at all. I've installed the "Chrome development extension".

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "debug-start",
            "postDebugTask": "debug-stop",
            "url": "http://192.168.242.128:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", 
            "skipFiles": [
              "<node_internals>/**",
              "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**",
              "bootstrap"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
            "runtimeArgs": [
              "--inspect-brk=covid.guest:9229",
              "start"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "home-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I start the app from "Run" menu, the development server starts, a chrome browser opens, and the resulting page has the spinning React logo and reads "Edit src/App.js and save to reload." The breakpoint is ignored. While the development server is running, the breakpoint is a hollow circle, and its tooltip reads "Breakpoint set but not yet bound".

The "DEBUG CONSOLE" contains:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: ...
```

The built-in terminal contains:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view home-react-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.242.128:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

Note that the browser is open on my Windows 10 host. The (local) IP address of the host is `192.168.242.128`.

When I stop the dev server, either by using the run bar or closing the browser, the terminal tells me I've stopped and the breakpoint returns to its solid red appearance.

I'm able to debug a node.js app generated by `express`, and it generates its own debug port along the lines of:

```
/home/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/v13.13.0/bin/node --inspect-brk=11875 bin/www
```

It looks to me as though I have to somehow get inside the webpack dev server. Yikes.

How do I get this technology stack to actually STOP at the breakpoint? What must I do to actually bind to the breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

After several days of intense poking around, I found the answer. It is to change the "chrome" entry in `launch.json` so that the value of "webRoot" is a full file path -- in this case `"/home/<user>/plain-react-app"`.

With that change, the source mapping works and the VSCode debugger stops as desired.

My learning curve would have been helped enormously by some simple and crisp explanatory text in the VSCode documentation about how "webRoot" is used and with some actual examples. I think my configuration (VSCode running on the host targeting javascript running on a guestVM) is fairly common, and I think this use of an explicit filepath will be needed whenever the browser runs on a different host from the server it connects to.

Comment: worked for me too! After LOTS of various config settings...this has to be a bug